# Why name attribute required in AngullarJs validation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-validation

Friends, I am new to angularjs please explain why **name** attribute required for angularjs validation

```
<form  name="lform" novalidate>
<input type="text"  name="userName" ng-model="userName" required novalidate/>
<span style="color:red" ng-show="lform.userName.$dirty && lform.userName.$invalid">
<span ng-show="lform.userName.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
</span>
<br/>
</form>
```

If I remove **name="userName"** code not working, please explain this.

```
Update: If I remove "ng-model" it is not working, but I can change "ngmodel='newName'" is working, please explain this reason also.
```

Comment: ["A form is an instance of FormController. The form instance can optionally be published into the scope using the `name` attribute.

Similarly, an input control that has the ngModel directive holds an instance of NgModelController.Such a control instance can be published as a property of the form instance using the name attribute on the input control. The `name` attribute specifies the name of the property on the form instance."](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#binding-to-form-and-control-state)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just how HTML form works, name describe the parameter that will be sent to the server.

Angular's approach is to extend HTML and its behaviour, instead of inventing the wheel. Angular encapsulates "form" (see ngForm directive) and extend it. Because name is the unique id of an input in a form, it is also the unique id of the input in ngForm's collection.

ng-model is another directive that bind the value of the input into a variable in the current scope, it doesn't have to hold the same value as name.

Let's take your example and change ng-model:

```
<form  name="lform" novalidate>
<input type="text"  name="userName" ng-model="object.name" required novalidate/>
<span style="color:red" ng-show="lform.userName.$dirty && lform.userName.$invalid">
<span ng-show="lform.userName.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
</span>
<br/>
</form>
```

The validation will work, but the variable that will be updated in your scope is "object.name".

To sum it up, lform.userName holds the metadata and object.name will hold the actual data.

Comment: why ng-model is required here, even If i give different name

Comment: ng-model allows you to actually bind the input into your scope. That what tells Angular that this input is part of your "FormController" and therefore needs to be validated and treated.

Comment: I agree that, but here I won't use object.name anywhere than why it is required attribute for validation

Comment: Got it in your comments later. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in your code.

```
<span ng-show="lform.userName.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
```

Angular is using the input name to store the error related information.

lform – your form name
username – your input name

Comment: If that is the case than why name="userName" ng-model="userName" should be same

Comment: Sorry, Got it now, But one more doubt why ng-model is required here, if it using name attribute

Comment: ng-model and name don't have to be the same, see my answer